# Tkinter button bind and parent deatroy

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code :

```
    print '1'
from Tkinter import *
print '2'
class myApp:

    print '3'
    def __init__(self,parent):
        print '4'

##        self.myparent = parent    line1
        print '11'

        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        print '12'
        self.myContainer1.pack()
        print '13'

        self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1,text="OK",background="green")
        print '14'
        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        print '15'
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",self.button1Click)
        print '16'

        self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1,text="Cancel",background="cyan")
        print '17'
        self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
        print '18'
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>",self.button2Click)
        print '19'


    def button1Click(self,event):

            print '5'

            if self.button1['background'] == 'green':
                print '20'
                self.button1['background'] ='tan'
                print '21'

            else:

                print '22'

                self.button1['background'] = 'yellow'

                print '23'

    def button2Click(self,event):

            print '6'

##            self.myparent.destroy()

            self.parent.destroy()

print '7'
root = Tk()
print '8'
myapp = myApp(root)
print '9'
root.mainloop()
print '10'
```

Error is :

```
    >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1
2
3
7
8
4
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
9
5
20
21
5
22
23
6
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1403, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\he00044.HALEDGEWOOD\Desktop\TkinterExamples\buttonBind.py", line 56, in button2Click
    self.parent.destroy()
AttributeError: myApp instance has no attribute 'parent'
10
>>>
```

This is when i comment line1

It may be becoz myapp is not finding parent.

But the concept is not clear.

Can anybody explain the concept in detail....

Answer (score 2):

Why ever did you comment out those two lines mentioning `self.myparent` and create a new one mentioning a mysterious, never-initialized `self.parent`?!  That's the start of your problem, of course -- looks like absurd, deliberate sabotage of code.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the incoming parameter parent to self.parent?

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    self.parent = parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not tkinter related, it's rather about object oriented design.

Class **myApp** has **__init__** method (constructor, the method that executes when object of that class is created), as well as two methods for button clicks. In button2Click method, you attempt to read attribute **self.parent** (translating as **myapp.parent**), but this property is not defined.

When you uncomment line 1, you won't get the error. This is because you are creating attribute **myapp.parent**, and you are assigning the Tk root widget to this attribute. This is necessary as all widgets you create have to receive their parent widget.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers so far are great. 
This may also help: [Fredrik Lundh's intro to Tkinter](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/).

Added some comments to your code that, along with the other answers, should help get you moving again:

```
import Tkinter

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent): # constructor
        self.parent = parent # the parent here is 'root'
        self.myContainer1 = Tkinter.Frame(self.parent) # create Frame w/ root as parent
        self.myContainer1.pack() # make Frame (myContainer1) visible
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self.myContainer1, 
                        text="OK", background="green") # add button as child of Frame
        self.button1.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT) # place button1 in Frame
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",self.button1Click) # bind left mouse button to button1Click method
        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self.myContainer1, text="Cancel", 
                        background="cyan")
        self.button2.pack(side=Tkinter.RIGHT)
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>", self.button2Click)

    def button1Click(self, event):
        if self.button1['background'] == 'green':
            self.button1['background'] ='tan'
        else:
            self.button1['background'] = 'yellow'

    def button2Click(self, event):
        self.parent.destroy() # the parent here is 'root', so you're ending the event loop

root = Tkinter.Tk()     # create root widget (a window)
myapp = MyApp(root)     # create instance of MyApp with root as the parent
root.mainloop()         # create event loop (ends when window is closed)
```